# Not able to center a div in flexbox

Tags: html, css

Hi so I just need some help on `flexbox`, ive looked at other people and even copied there code to test but for some reason it isnt working. I'm trying to get a `div` with content aligned in the center top of a website. Here is my current code,

### index.html

```
<div class="header"> 
  <div class="headerContent">
    <h1>TEST<h1>
  </div>
</div
```

### style.css

```
html { 
  display: flex;
}
.header {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}
 .headerContent {
    background-color: #2C374C; 
    width: 100%;
   justify-content: center;
}
```

Comment: take the width off `.headerContent`, works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

when you use `flex-direction: column;`, to center horizontally use `align-items: center;` instead of `justify-content: center;`

You also have set a `height` property.

Example:

```css
.header{
  display: flex;
  height: 300px;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  
  background: red
}
```

```html
<header class="header">
  <div>centered</div>
</header>
```

Comment: good one ......

Answer (score 0):

it seems you are doing the right thing but on the wrong element. Your are treating the `.header` id as the parent container when it is the child.

In this case the container hierarchy is the following `html` -> `header` -> `.headerContent`

So to center `header` you need to **act** on its parent. Imagine it as a parent giving order to its child (literally).

```
html { 
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

> by doing this the parent component is justifying its content (children)

I would also recommend instead of using html to create another div container to be the parent of your header div like so

```css
.headerContainer { 
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: red
}
.header {
  display: flex;
}
 .headerContent {
    background-color: #2C374C; 
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
    <div class="headerContainer">
      <div class="header"> 
  <div class="headerContent">
    <h1>TEST<h1>
  </div>
 </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think just like this

```css
.header {
  width: 100%;
}
.headerContent {
  background-color: #2c374c;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <div class="header">
    <div class="headerContent">
      <h1>Test</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</html>
```